# Mono mkbundle throws 'IKVM.Reflection.BadImageFormatException'

Tags: c#, deployment, mono, mkbundle

I've been trying to compile or bundle my application using mkbundle.
This is the script I'm executing:

```
set -o errexit
set -o nounset

mono_version="3.2.3"
export MONO=/cygdrive/c/progra~2/Mono-$mono_version

machineconfig=$PROGRAMFILES\\Mono-$mono_version\\etc\\mono\\4.0\\machine.config

export PATH=$PATH:$MONO/bin

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$MONO/lib/pkgconfig

icon_name='"icon.ico"'

echo "1 ICON $icon_name" > icon.rc

export CC="i686-pc-mingw32-gcc icon.o -U _WIN32"

output_name=Output.exe

mkbundle JiraTempoApp.exe MonoPosixHelper.dll gtk-sharp.dll glib-sharp.dll atk-sharp.dll gdk-sharp.dll glade-sharp.dll glib-sharp.dll pango-sharp.dll RestSharp.dll JiraRestLib.dll --deps --machine-config "$machineconfig" -o $output_name -z

rm icon.rc 
rm icon.o

cp $MONO/bin/mono-2.0.dll .
cp $MONO/bin/zlib1.dll .

./$output_name
```

I had to add MonoPosixHelper.dll because I got a EntryPoint not found error. Now I got this weird error:

```
$ ./mkbundle_cygwin.sh
OS is: Windows
WARNING:
  Check that the machine.config file you are bundling
  doesn't contain sensitive information specific to this machine.
Sources: 11 Auto-dependencies: True

Unhandled Exception:
IKVM.Reflection.BadImageFormatException: Exception of type 'IKVM.Reflection.BadImageFormatException' was thrown.
  at IKVM.Reflection.Reader.PEReader.RvaToFileOffset (UInt32 rva) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Reader.ModuleReader.Read (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Reader.ModuleReader..ctor (IKVM.Reflection.Reader.AssemblyReader assembly, IKVM.Reflection.Universe universe, System.IO.Stream stream, System.String location) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.OpenRawModule (System.IO.Stream stream, System.String location) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.OpenRawModule (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.LoadFile (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.LoadAssembly (System.String assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.LoadAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 sources) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: IKVM.Reflection.BadImageFormatException: Exception of type 'IKVM.Reflection.BadImageFormatException' was thrown.
  at IKVM.Reflection.Reader.PEReader.RvaToFileOffset (UInt32 rva) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Reader.ModuleReader.Read (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Reader.ModuleReader..ctor (IKVM.Reflection.Reader.AssemblyReader assembly, IKVM.Reflection.Universe universe, System.IO.Stream stream, System.String location) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.OpenRawModule (System.IO.Stream stream, System.String location) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.OpenRawModule (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.LoadFile (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.LoadAssembly (System.String assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.LoadAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 sources) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My .exe is succesfully running on Windows and Ubuntu but I'm trying to bundle it so that users don't have to download mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkbundle` can't handle dynamically linked libraries as `MonoPosixHelper.dll`.
If you want you application to run without mono, you will need to deploy this (and other libraries) together with your application on the target system.

If you want to run your application on Ubuntu and don't want the user to install libgtk2.0-cil, you will also have to deploy `libatksharpglue-2.so libgdksharpglue-2.so libglibsharpglue-2.so libgtksharpglue-2.so libpangosharpglue-2.so` as the `*-sharp.dll`s require them.

Then make sure the target system is able to find these libraries. Either by defining `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or by creating DLL-maps on the build system (which is tricky and can get a little tedious).

You can also pass the `--static` parameter to `mkbundle` to include all needed mono libraries directly in your bundle (see manpage for details).
Also, execute your final bundle only with `MyApp.exe` not with `mono MyApp.exe`.

Here are some options to do this for Linux targets. I didn't use `mkbundle` with mono on Windows, yet, but only compiled against .NET with `msbuild`, which also creates `.msi` files.

### Option 1:

```
$DEPS = "gtk-sharp.dll glib-sharp.dll atk-sharp.dll gdk-sharp.dll glade-sharp.dll glib-sharp.dll pango-sharp.dll RestSharp.dll JiraRestLib.dll"
mkbundle --static -o JiraTempoApp JiraTempoApp.exe --deps $DEPS --machine-config "$machineconfig" -z
```

Then make sure to deploy `MonoPosixHelper.dll`. and the other `.so` files depicted above to your system. To start your application, execute

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/deployed/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH JiraTempoApp
```

However, I cannot verify that this method with setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works at the moment.

### Option 2:

Build with the same command as in Option 1, but execute from the directory of your deployed libs:

```
cd /path/to/deployed/libs; /path/to/JiraTempoApp
```

### Option 3:

This is a little more complicated: You need to find your the dependency `.dll`s and their `.dll.config` files on your build system. Copy them to your build directory and the dll mapping in the config file with a mapping that includes a relative path to the location of the `.so` files on the **target** system.
This way, the dll mapping gets packed by mkbundle and the packed executable will be able to find the deployed `.so`s on the target system.
I once wrote a [Makefile](https://github.com/OpenDataSpace/CmisSync/blob/develop/Makefile.fatbuild) for an application that uses this option, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the command that I should execute

Comment: @sburnicki Im trying to do use your method 3 on MacOSX.I tried copying all the dylib and glue files mentioned here http://ascend4.org/Porting_to_Mac/gtk-mac-bundler . It does not work.Do i need to set the configure the path or something.please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that MonoPosixHelper.dll is a managed library? AFAIK mkbundle can only work on managed code. You should still use this DLL (leave it in a folder where it will be loaded, like in a folder you define with LD_LIBRARY_PATH) to avoid the EntryNotFound exception but you shouldn't use it as an argument to the mkbundle command.

Comment: I've tried that but after compiling I get the error invalid CIL image when I try to execute it.

Comment: That was my full error. When I executed mono Myapp.exe I got: Unable to execute program invaled CIL image.